# (Micro) Services dependencies and relations documentation

Tags: web-services, dependencies, microservices, documentation

When you have so many services, let's say more than 50 services and you want to know the relation between services, for instance you want to know which services have hard dependency on each other and which have soft dependency on each other, meaning when a service goes down and doesn't function anymore which other services will not work.
Basically for providing a level of High availability and uptime (SLA) we also need this.
and also when a new person joins the team there should be some kind of documentation to see what services we have and how is the dependency tree.
what kind of relation they have ? just messaging through a message broker or direct requests ?
Are those services working in just test environment or prod environment ? or both ?
What tools and softwares are there to help us cover this.

Answer (score 0):

I am just now also looking into this question. Especially modelling dependencies between services.

In my opinion you can go into two directions

- Service Registry
- Configuration Management DB

There are a lot of full blown Service Registries out there, which do are not only static documentation, but services als register themselves with the service registry and others can discover the service to user there automatically.

- [Eureka](http://github.com/Netflix/eureka)  related to Netflix Open Source Stack (Netflix OSS)
- [Consul](http://www.consul.io/)
- [Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/)
- [Etcd](http://github.com/coreos/etcd)

For me the Service Registry option might be to complex and I am going into the the direction of a simple CMBD